# How to display a simple hollow asterisk rectangle in console?

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops

Could someone advise me on a simple way to implement hollow rectangles in C#?

I have been able to make a simple rectangle, but hollow rectangle programs I've looked at either contained or arrays or were pretty convoluted. For instance, the solution on [another forum](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/117379-hollow-square.html) that seems too challenging, and [this answer on CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23299/11074) is too difficult to understand.

This is what I've done, which displays a simple (filled) rectangle. How to output a hollow rectangle using `if` logic if possible?

```
class Nested_Loops_Hollow_Rectangles
{
    public void RunExercise()
    {
        // how are now supposed to make this hollow?
        // columns are side by side, rows is number of top to bottom
        // see tut
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the HollowRectanglePrinter Program.");
        Console.WriteLine("How many columns wide should the rectangle be?"); //i.e. 4
        int iColMax, iRowMax;
        string userChoiceC = Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.TryParse(userChoiceC, out iColMax);
        Console.WriteLine("How many rows tall should the rectangle be?  "); //i.e. 4
        string userChoiceR = Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.TryParse(userChoiceR, out iRowMax);
        Console.WriteLine("Here you go:");

        if (iRowMax > 0 || iColMax > 0) 
        {
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < iRowMax; iRow++) 
            {
                for (int iCol = 0; iCol < iColMax; iCol++) 
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The essential part of your application can be reduced to:

```
private void DrawFillRectangle(int width, int height)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This, by the way (separating the logic and the input by putting the logic in a dedicated method) is what you *should* be doing. See [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) for more information.

The previous method draws a filled rectangle, so how can you draw a hollow one?

Start looking at the output. For instance, for (5, 3), the output is:

```
*****
*****
*****
```

and what you want is to have:

```
*****
*   *
*****
```

How can you do that? Probably by replacing stars by spaces in some cases. Which ones?

Well, look again at the output. The first row is untouched, so the condition where you use spaces instead of stars is limited to rows other than the first one, that is:

```
private void DrawRectangle(int width, int height)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
        {
            if (y > 0)
            {
                // Print either a star or a space.
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Now you must include the other cases in your condition: the first column, and the last column and row.

In order to combine conditions, you can use `&&` and `||` operators. The first one means that the condition is true if both operands are true, and the second one means that either the first or the second operand is true.

It might be that your final condition will become too difficult to read. There are two things you can do. The first thing is to use intermediary variables. For instance:

```
if (a && b && c && d)
{
}
```

can be refactored into:

```
var e = a && b;
var f = c && d;
if (e && f)
{
}
```

if it makes sense to regroup `a` with `b` and `c` with `d`. A second thing you can do is to put the condition in a separate method, which may improve readability if you find a good name for the method:

```
private void DrawRectangle(int width, int height)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
        {
            if (this.IsInsideRectangle(x, y))
            {
                // Print either a star or a space.
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

private bool IsInsideRectangle(int x, int y)
{
    return y > 0 && ...
}
```

This is hopefully all you need to do the exercise. Depending of your progression in the course, you may also be interested in those aspects:

1. You may avoid repeating code in an `if/else` block, so instead of:

   ```
   if (...)
   {
       Console.Write(" ");
   }
   else
   {
       Console.Write("*");
   }
   ```

   you may end up writing only only `Write()`:

   ```
   Console.Write(...)
   ```

   What [C# operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) can you use for that?
2. It is a good practice for a method to validate its input before doing its job. If you've already learnt what exceptions are, how can they be used to validate `width` and `height`? Why in the current situation it may make sense to *not* filter negative and zero values (in other words, would the application crash if, for instance, `width` is equal to `-5`)?

Comment: I realized part of the answer when I glanced at your code. This was very well written.

Answer (score 1):

```
class emptyRectangle:Shape
{
    byte width;
    byte height;
    public emptyRectangle(byte width,byte height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public override void area()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n----------");

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && k > 0)
                {
                    if (i < height - 1 && k < width - 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    else
                        Console.Write('*');
               }
                else
                    Console.Write("*");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain why this works? And why did you use `byte` instead of `int` for `width` and `height`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a single IF statement where you are drawing the character:

> if it is the first or last row or the first or last column, write the *
>   else the space.

For more fun, make a variable sized rectangular "hole" in the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int width = 0, height = 0;

        width = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        height = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
            {
                if ((i == 1 || i == height || j == 1 || j == width))
                    Console.Write("*");
                else
                    Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, you should edit the answer to explain exactly what your approach is in plain words, too.