# Print same number multiple times to form rectangle of given size

Tags: c#, for-loop, console

I have school assignment to create console program that creates a Field of Numbers (rectangular shape) with the Input of the User using basic `for` loop. Meaning, the User will write which Number should be used to fill the Field, and how high and wide the Field should be.

Here is the Code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Hey! Which Number do you want to use to fill the field?");
        int fieldNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Okay, how big should be the lenght?");
        int fieldSizeX = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Allright, how big should the height be?");
        int fieldSizeY = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Clear();

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < fieldSizeX && j < fieldSizeY; i++, j++)
        {
        }
```

Comment: you need to read up on the Console.Read(). do a simple google search on `Console.Read and Console.ReadLine` also tell us what the purpose and or your thinking is in regards to using a for loop.. if you want to store values and then display later.. use a List<string> or something

Comment: Its to practise for School, its just a certain task that i have to complete, and im stuck here since 2 Days, i've been trying to google a Solution, but i just cant find the Solution to my Question.

Comment: just curious @Donvah was part of your school assignment to use a for loop if so then the provided solution would do the trick.. can you clarify

Comment: I see "field" means "rectangle"... Like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413018/how-to-display-a-simple-hollow-asterisk-rectangle-in-console

Comment: I've updated title/some text to reflect "rectangle" - feel free to improve more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the loops apart, you need to write out X*Y elements.

```
//For each row (y)
for (int y = 0; y < fieldSizeY; y++)
{
    //For each column (x)
    for (int x = 0; x < fieldSizeX; x++)
    {
        //Now you need to repeat the same number for each x, but no new line.
        Console.Write(fieldNumber)
    } 
    //Stick the new line on the end of the row to start the next row
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: this can be done without a loop based on the example the OP's code that he's shown in the question.. from what I see this could have been done 
`Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The values for FieldNumber are {0} FieldSizeX are {1} FieldSizeY are {2}, fieldNumber, fieldSizeX, fieldSizeY));`

Comment: This is the solution , he wanted something simple since he is just starting !!